# Can I convert this cursor and while loop to a set based solution?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I currently am writing a script where I have a tree as well a set of known parent nodes (none of which are the root node)and a set of known child nodes. For each child node, I have to find a direct descendant of one of the parent nodes that is also a parent of the child node. For each child node, only one such value exists, but there could be any number of nodes between each child node and its corresponding target.

What I have now is a cursor that iterates through each child node and uses a while loop to travel up the tree until it finds a node with a parent in the set of parent nodes, and that is the match. My question is, can I solve this without a cursor or the while loop in a set-based way? I'm not a sql expert, but could not come up with a way to do this using merges or joins.

Comment: Can you give us some sample data?

Comment: If you have a tree structure, then any node (including leafs) has exactly one parent.  Either all nodes in the path to the parent meet your conditions or none do.

Comment: Edit your question to include table structure and sample data (as text, please), and tag your question with the version of SQL Server you're using.  See [ask] and [mcve] for additional details on what information is helpful to have in a SO question.

Comment: You may have some success searching for _common table expression_ (CTE). It's a common way to recursively process data, e.g. walking through trees. Some of the links on the right side of the page under **Related** may also be helpful.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 2):

When working with apparently difficult tree problems, it is often useful to build an "ancestors table". This isn't just a SQL thing, it's a common tool used when dealing with hierarchies.

An ancestors table contains all the connections between the various nodes. So if you have a graph with root A, B as a child of A, and C as a child of B, your ancestors table contains a row for the connection from B to A, and a row for the connection from C to B, *and* a row for the connection from C to A, and then optionally a "root" row (from A to A with a length of zero).

Once you have such a table most problems become a lot easier to formulate. For example, your problem would turn into a fairly straightforward set of joins to do the following:

> Find the set of rows R1(parent, child, length) in Ancestors where R1.parent is a KnownParent and the path length is 1 *(this gives you the direct descendants of KnownParents)*, and then find the set of rows R2(parent, child) in Ancestors where R2.parent = R1.child, and R2.child is a KnownChilld

Generating an ancestors table can be done with a recursive CTE, has mentioned by HABO. There's an existing stackoverflow answer about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145970/recursive-cte-to-find-all-ancestors-of-all-items)

An ancestors table isn't the only way to answer this question, but it's such a useful thing to learn I suggest using one. You don't have to persist the ancestors of course, just join directly to the output of the recursive cte.